# Entity Framework, Update The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0

I wrote a Silverlight MVVM (SimpleMVVM toolkit) Ria Services App with EntityFramework Model generated from exsisting DB.
At first ViewModel of Page which display list parent entities I load parents, after selecting one, I can further go to edition page, where I do menagent of child entities. Before that, I pass parent Entity by pageDataHelper - key value pair Dictionary, which it holds, to ViewModel of Edition Page, and refresh it from database.
Next, I can load by entity primary key, it's childs to ListBox. By this, i can do CRUD's of childs. Anfortunatly, when I want to update one one of them, I got:

> The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_Pozycje_Kosztorysy" The conflict occurred in database
>   "D:...\APP_DATA\EMS.MDF", table "dbo.Kosztorysy", column 'KosID'.

Aplication makes updates in DB, but entityframework always throws exception, which I handle...
Both tables in db have set On Update/Delete Cascade. 
Entities looks:

```
internal sealed class KosztorysMetadata
    {
   public int KosID { get; set; }//Primary Key
   public EntityCollection<Pozycja> Pozycje { get; set; } //Childs           
    }
}
  internal sealed class PozycjaMetadata
    {
  public int KosID { get; set; }// Foreign Key
  public int PozID { get; set; }//Primary Key
   }
}
```

In App.Web, functins to get entities:

```
   public IQueryable<Kosztorys> GetKosztorysByID(int id)
   {
    var query = from k in this.ObjectContext.Kosztorysy
                    where k.KosID==id
                    select k;
    return query;
}
  public IQueryable<Pozycja> GetPozycjeGlowne(Int32 id)
    {
        var query = from k in this.ObjectContext.Pozycje
                    where k.KosID == id && (k.NadPozID == null || k.TypRMS == 0 || k.TypRMS == TypRMSBVals.Dzial)
                    select k;
        return query;
    }
```

In ViewModel;

```
class KosztorysViewModel{
   public Kosztorys WybranyKosztorys
        {
            get { return wybranyKosztorys; }
            set{  WybranyKosztorys = value;}} 
        private ObservableCollection<Kosztorys> kosztorysy;
        public ObservableCollection<Kosztorys> Kosztorysy{}}

  public void OdsiwezKosztorys()//Refresh parent
        {  this.serviceAgent.PobKosztorys(WybranyKosztorys.KosID, (encje, ex) => { kosztorysOdswiezony(encje, blad); });
                         }
 void kosztorysOdswiezony(List<Kosztorys> encje, Exception exc) //Refreshed Parent
        { Kosztorysy = new ObservableCollection<Kosztorys>(encje);
                            WybranyKosztorys = Kosztorysy[0];}

      public void PobDzialy()
            {
                if (WybranyKosztorys != null)
                {
                    this.serviceAgent.PobGlownePozycje(WybranyKosztorys.KosID, (encje, ex) => dzialyPobrane(encje, ex));
                               }
            }
     void dzialyPobrane(List<Pozycja> encje, Exception exc) //callback
            {          
                                    Dzialy.Clear();
                                    Dzialy = new ObservableCollection<Pozycja>(encje);
                }}
```

What's wrong? I use ;EF4.3, Silverlight 5, MS SQL Server 2008R

Comment: Does it work if you write the statement in sql against the database directly (using the same Ids)?

Comment: It works when I do this by Server Menagment Studio,